# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date on some devices only

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm facing a very bizarre issue.
While parsing this string `2016-09-06 05:18:06.023 PM` I get the following exception - `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-09-06 05:18:06.023 PM" (at offset 24)`

Weird part is that the device on which this exception has occurred is a friend's **Nexus 5**.  However, if I debug this same string on my **Nexus 5** / **several other emulators**, it works fine.

Here is the code that I'm using. `SimpleDateFormat` belongs to `java.text` package. `Date` belongs to `java.util` package

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatGMT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss.SSS a");
    formatGMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    try {
      date = formatGMT.parse("2016-09-06 05:18:06.023 PM");
     } catch (ParseException e) {
      Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, "DB Insertion error", e.getMessage().toString());
      Crashlytics.logException(e);
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Here is the full stack trace.

```
  # Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace  Wed, 07 Sep 2016 03:37:44 GMT


# Platform: android

# Bundle Identifier: com.mypackage.app
# Issue #: 306

# Date: 2016-09-06T17:18:04Z
# OS Version: 6.0.1
# Device: Nexus 5
# RAM Free: 36.5%
# Disk Free: 11%

#0. Crashed: pool-3-thread-3: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
       at com.mypackage.app.MyService$16$1.execute(MyService.java:1670)
       at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1187)
       at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

--

Non-fatal Exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-09-06 05:18:06.023 PM" (at offset 24)
       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
       at com.mypackage.MyService$16$1.execute(MyService.java:1670)
       at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1187)
       at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#0. Crashed: pool-3-thread-3: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
       at com.mypackage.MyService$16$1.execute(MyService.java:1670)
       at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1187)
       at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please post full stacktrace - maybe we can dig into SDF code to find out why :-)

Comment: Added the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be possible it can be affected by Symbols For am/pm in device default locale, so try to use locale as below to parse date it will help you.

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatGMT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:mm:ss.SSS a", Locale.US);

      formatGMT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

      try 
      {
             date = formatGMT.parse("2016-09-06 05:18:06.023 PM");
      } 
      catch (ParseException e)
      {
             Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, "DB Insertion error", e.getMessage().toString());
             Crashlytics.logException(e);
             e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll give it a shot and get back with the exact solution. I'll try both ways.