# Android Unparsable Date : Jan 06, 2017

Tags: android, locale, simpledateformat

The funciton I'm using is

```
public static String getFormatedDate(String dateVal) {
    String tempDate = null;
    Locale systemLocale = Locale.getDefault();

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy",
                systemLocale);
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateVal);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        tempDate = sdf.format(date);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApplicationLog.log(TAG, e);
    }

    return tempDate;
}
```

In many devices this function is working properly, but in one of the devices the exception is being raised while parsing the date. Does this exception is something to do with the `Locale.getDefault()`?. If yes what changes should I do? Thanks.

Calling the Function

```
Utilities.getFormatedDate(date);
```

And the exception is...

```
Utilities:java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 06, 2017" (at offset 0)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Also can you share the code where you are calling this method?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just try not passing the locale.

Comment: @AnuragSingh I can't remove locale, is there any changes in the Android settings that can be done.

Comment: @AbhishekJain i have added the stack trace and the exception. Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361220/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-on-some-devices-only

Comment: @sandy Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @AbhishekJain since i wasn't allowed to make any code changes , i had to re-enter the data in the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse the date from a locale dependent format `"MMM dd, yyyy"` and setting the system locale. Try passing a locale which conforms with your format. For example `Locale.US`. Change your method like this,

```
public static String getFormatedDate(String dateVal) {
    String tempDate = null;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy",
                Locale.US);
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(dateVal);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        tempDate = sdf.format(date);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApplicationLog.log(TAG, e);
    }

    return tempDate;
}
```