# Unparseable Date error on some devices with same API

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I found a very strange problem with the app I'm developing right now. I'm reading data from a JSON object to draw a graph, and everything works just fine when using Genymotion Galaxy S6 5.1.0 (API 22), but when I got to try it on my physical devices (Huawei P7 and Moto G both 5.1.1) I got Unparseable Date error and my graph obviously stays blank.

Here's the code that's failing:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, HH:mm:ss");
try {
        formatter1.parse("Aug 01, 10:30:00");
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();};
```

And this is the Stack Trace I'm getting in logcat:

```
    08-21 16:37:37.200 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Aug 01, 10:30:00" (at offset 0)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6078)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5569)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
08-21 16:37:37.210 16528-16528/com.example.gonzalo.raspacuariofirebase W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

I am aware that there's another thread with a problem very similar to mine ([java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date on some devices only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361220/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-on-some-devices-only)) but the fact is I'm not using AM/PM times so I don't think I should be getting this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you will want to include the year to avoid this error

Comment: You're not using AM/PM but you're using a month name in English (Aug), and both are related to the same reason: they are locale sensitive data. You should use `Locale.US` or `Locale.ENGLISH` as suggested in [@Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45800256/7605325)

Comment: Another detail is that the input has no year and `SimpleDateFormat` will get a default value for it (in my machine, it sets to `1970`). Depending on what you're doing with the parsed date, this might lead to incorrect results.

Comment: @petey, I believe that `SimpleDateFormat` will happily give you a default year of 1970. Not that it’s what you would typically want, but I doubt that it will throw any exception for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a locale otherwise you can run into these errors:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

For example:

`SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);`

> The SimpleDateFormat class is locale-sensitive. If you instantiate
>   SimpleDateFormat without a Locale parameter, it will format the date
>   and time according to the default Locale. Both the pattern and the
>   Locale determine the format. For the same pattern, SimpleDateFormat
>   may format a date and time differently if the Locale varies.